# Node analysis in Thevenin Equivalent

Tags: thevenin, nodal-analysis, norton

I have the following circuit and imagine at the right side of the capacitor there is an open circuit with two terminals A,B. There is one dependent source and one independent source.Therefore \$R_{th} = \frac{V_{oc}}{i_{sc}}\$. Regarding the calculation of \$V_{oc}\$  I want to perform the node analysis.

[image]

\$V(t)= 6 \cos(10t+ \angle 0)\$

\$V = 6 \angle 0\$
\$\omega = 10 \$

\$Z_{c} = -\frac{j}{\omega C} = \frac{j}{ 10 \frac{1}{10} }=-j\$

I have a difficulty to perform node analysis with \$V_{1}\$ because there are in series a lot of elements so I transform the circuit :

\$I = \frac{V}{Z_{R}} = \frac{6 \angle 0}{2} = 3 \angle 0\$

[image]

Now I think I am ready for the Node Analysis so I have the node equation :

\$-3 +\frac{V_{0}}{2}+\frac{V_{1}}{4}+\frac{V_{2}}{-j} =0 \$

with constrains : \$V_{0} - V_{1} = -i_{1}/2\$

\$V_{1}-V_{2} = -i_{1}\$

Which means that the \$V_{oc} = V_{2}\$.

Am I correct ?

Regarding the \$i_{sc}\$

[image]

No the capacitor is parallel with a short-circuit as well as the 4 ohm resistor so they do not play any role.All the 0 current goes to the dependent source therefore also this excluded.The 2 ohm resistor is again parallel with the short-circuit.Thus the \$i_{sc}= 3 \angle 0 A\$

Comment: In this example, converting the voltage source to a current source isn't going to help. You should focus on defining what \$i_1\$ is in terms of V1 (same as V2) and the capacitor.

Comment: @Andyaka \$V_2 - V_1 = i_1\$.But if I do not transform the circuit I will have two nodes \$V_{1},V_{2}\$. I do not know how to write the node equation for \$V_{1}\$.It confuses me. From \$V_{1}\$  all the way to the ground I have in series a dependent source a resistor and a independent source.Can you help me with this ?

Comment: @HomerJay Does [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUBZF.png) help you any with setting up nodal equations? (I suspect you may be in the deep end of the pool, right now. But perhaps you are keeping up and I am over-thinking.)

Comment: @periblepsis it is an old exam problem that I am trying to solve.From your picture  I suspect \$V_2 - V_1 = 0 \$ ?

Comment: @HomerJay Yes. That would be true. But inserting the voltage supply there allows you to specify a current through it for purposes of nodal analysis. Just having a wire only means that there's only one node, not two, there. You have to include that 0 V voltage supply in order to separate the nodes for analysis. Just FYI.

Comment: @periblepsis the capacitor is in parallel with the 4 ohm resistor.So the current I as depicted in the picture is actually the the current in the new element.Am I correct ?

Comment: Do you want to find Voc and Isc using nodal analysis or what? To find Voc voltage you need to disconnect the capacitor. Thus, I1 = 0, and CCVS voltage is also 0V so, Voc = 6V * 4Ω/(2Ω + 4Ω) = 4V or -3 + Vo/2 + Vo/4 = 0

Comment: @G36 why to disconnect the capacitor ?

Comment: Because this is what we do when we want to find Vos = Vth (Thevenin's voltage).

Comment: @G36 I didn't know that.So if a circuit has a capacitor or an inductor we remove them ,we calculate R_th , Vth and we connect them again in the terminals ?

Comment: So you don't know how to do a Thevenin equivalent circuit?

Comment: @g36 apparently yes.

Comment: @periblepsis I appreciate your advice and your help.I am self learning linear circuits.So probably many things are being understood poorly by me.

Comment: @HomerJay Seriously, I really do understand how these ideas can get lodged into mind. I'm almost certain the same exact thing happened to me. So I'm not complaining nor am I saying anything critical. Different people have differing starting "tools" when they first face electronics analysis. A well-trained person in mathematics and/or physics, without any experiences in electronics, will take to this like a duck to water because they already have these ideas that they can bring over. But many of us have to construct this "the hard way."

Comment: @periblepsis I have revisited this problem and I think that the node equations (from my perspective, ignore the V2 node and keep the V0 and V1) are : for V0: \$-3 +\frac{V_0}{2}+i =0\$ ,for V1: \$-i+\frac{V_1}{4}+\frac{V_2}{-j}\$ under the constrain equations : \$i_{1}=\frac{V_1}{-j}\$ and \$V_1 - V_2 = \frac{-i_{1}} {2}\$ am I correct ?

Comment: @HomerJay Do you have N unknowns and N equations there? (I think it doesn't match. But I'm not sure.)

Comment: @periblepsis I have  2 unknowns v1 and v2 with 2 equations.

Comment: @HomerJay Looking at your diagram, it is not possible for V1 and V2 to be different. They must be the same because they are wired together.

Comment: @periblepsis I meant v0 and v1.These are the nodes (unknowns).

Comment: @HomerJay You probably need to rewrite your question in comments above, then. I'm not sure what you want to change up there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take your 2nd schematic (I like solving that one better):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0W5al.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that I've added an unknown current. This is the current that must exist between the two nodes, \$V_0\$ and \$V_1\$. This current is not the same as \$I_1\$, as the current in \$R_2\$ is part of \$I_{V_A}\$ and is not a part of \$I_1\$. I need to add this because nodal deals with the sum of currents.

For KCL on node \$V_0\$ we know that that there are two currents exiting the node, \$I_{V_A}\$ and \$I_{R_1}\$ and one current entering the node, \$I_A\$. These two must be equal, so we can write: \$I_A=I_{V_A}+I_{R_1}\$, where \$I_{R_1}=\frac{V_0}{R_1}\$.

For KCL on node \$V_1\$ we know that that there are two currents exiting the node, \$I_1\$ and \$I_{R_2}\$ and one current entering the node, \$I_{V_A}\$. These two also must be equal, so we can write: \$I_{V_A}=I_1+I_{R_2}\$, where \$I_{R_2}=\frac{V_1}{R_2}\$ and \$I_1=j\,V_1\$.

We also happen to know that there's a relationship between \$V_0\$ and \$V_1\$. The KVL is: \$V_A=V_1-V_0=\frac12 I_1\$. Or put another way: \$V_1=V_0+V_A=V_0+\frac12 I_1\$.

All of these can be put together. The first two are the KCL for the two nodes. The third is the KVL relationship between the two nodes:

$$\begin{align*}
I_A&=I_{V_A}+\frac{V_0}{R_1}\tag{KCL for $V_0$}
\\\\
I_{V_A}&=j\,V_1+\frac{V_1}{R_2}\tag{KCL for $V_1$}
\\\\
V_1&=V_0+\frac12 j\,V_1\tag{KVL: $V_0$ to $V_1$}
\end{align*}$$

I'll use [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) to solve the above (I'll just substitute in the known resistor and current values, directly):

```
var('V0,V1,IVA')
j = I
e1 = Eq( 3, V0/2 + IVA )
e2 = Eq( IVA, j*V1 + V1/4 )
e3 = Eq( V1, V0 + j*V1/2 )
solve( [ e1, e2, e3 ], [ V0, V1, IVA ] )
{V0: 1 - 3*I, V1: 2 - 2*I, IVA: 5/2 + 3*I/2}
```

From this, I can work out the details:

$$\begin{align*}
& 1-j\, 3&&V_0\\
&3.16227766\: &&\angle -71.5650512^\circ\\
\\
& 2-j\, 2&&V_1\\
& 2.82842712\: &&\angle -45^\circ\\
\\
& 5/2+j\, 3/2&&I_{V_A}\\
& 2.91547595\: &&\angle -30.9637565^\circ
\end{align*}$$

If I put this into LTspice I need to add that voltage source I'd mentioned earlier to separate the nodes and measure the capacitor current for the purposes of the dependent voltage source:

[image]

I've selected out \$V_1\$ to find it's peak. You can see that LTspice reports a value that is almost identical to my computed magnitude above. Above I say it is \$2.82842712\:\text{V}\$ and LTspice reports it as \$2.8284271\:\text{V}\$. Close enough.